# Почему не получается установить приложение для отладки через Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, отладка, apk

Есть приложение в google play. Оно стоит на тестовом девайсе. После то же приложение ставится на устройство через студию. Раньше просто вылезало предупреждение о том, что версии несовместимы и надо удалить уже стоящее приложение. После этого все нормально проходило.
Сейчас как обычно вылезло окно с продолжением удалить, после еще одно:
[image]
Затем студия повисела секунд 30 в состоянии "Installing APK", затем упала, т.к. не смогла его удалить (на телефоне приложения не видно, студия раз 10 просила его удалить, ничего не менялось).
Вот что я вижу во вкладке run:
[image]

Comment: Вам что важнее узнать - почему не получается установить или как установить?

Comment: @Эникейщик, скорее как, но поняв почему скорее всего станет понятно как.

Comment: Девайс виртуальный или железный?

Comment: Девайс железный.

Comment: Банальная перезагрузка девайса обычно помогает: либо приложение появится и можно его вручную удалить, либо исчезнет.

Comment: Не помогала, пробовал.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема возникла из-за копирования проекта через файловую систему. Решение есть здесь:http://www.cyberforum.ru/android-dev/thread2081496.html